# Some installed font within a font family does not take effect

Tags: windows, fonts, emacs

I generated a font family (Ricty) using the script on [this site](https://rictyfonts.github.io/). There are four font files (styles) with four font styles:

- Ricty-Regular.ttf
- Ricty-Bold.ttf
- Ricty-Oblique.ttf
- Ricty-BoldOblique.ttf

I installed these files on Windows 10.

- (Situation 1) If install `Ricty-Regular.ttf` and `Ricty-Bold.ttf` and then `Ricty-Oblique.ttf` and `Ricty-BoldOblique.ttf`, in Control Panel > Fonts, only `Ricty-Regular.ttf` and `Ricty-Bold.ttf` showed. (Sorry for the screenshots is Japanese)

  [image]
- (Situation 2) If install `Ricty-Oblique.ttf` and `Ricty-BoldOblique.ttf` firstly, and then other two fonts, only these fonts displayed on Control Panel > fonts.
  [image]
- (Other situation) For `Ricty-Regular.ttf` and `Ricty-Oblique.ttf`, whichever installed first will win (show on Control Panel). Similarly, for `Ricty-Bold.ttf` and `Ricty-BoldOblique.ttf`, whichever installed first will win (show on Control Panel).
- On whichever situation, all four fonts will be showed on Settings > Fonts.
  [image]

I set Emacs (Spacemacs) to use this font family, in situation 1, all characters are in normal style, and in situation 2, all characters are in oblique style. (FYI, in situation 2, VSCode can show normal style).

**UPDATE**

Checked the values of tables using [OT Master Light 3.70](https://www.fontmaster.nl/test-demo.html).

| Font Table | Field | Ricty-Regular.ttf | Ricty-Oblique.ttf | Ricty-Bold.ttf | Ricty-BoldOblique.ttf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| head | macStyle | 0x0000 | 0x0000 | 0x0000 | 0x0000 |
| name | name IDs 0 | <long copyright string> | <long copyright string> | <long copyright string> | <long copyright string> |
|  | name IDs 1 | Ricty | Ricty | Ricty | Ricty |
|  | name IDs 2 | Regular | Oblique | Bold | Bold Oblique |
|  | name IDs 3 | FontForge 2.0 : Ricty Regular : 27-11-2021 | FontForge 2.0 : Ricty Oblique : 27-11-2021 | FontForge 2.0 : Ricty Bold : 27-11-2021 | FontForge 2.0 : Ricty Bold Oblique : 27-11-2021 |
|  | name IDs 4 | Ricty Regular | Ricty Oblique | Ricty Bold | Ricty Bold Oblique |
|  | name IDs 5 | Version 4.1.1 | Version 4.1.1 | Version 4.1.1 | Version 4.1.1 |
|  | name IDs 6 | Ricty-Regular | Ricty-Oblique | Ricty-Bold | Ricty-BoldOblique |
|  | name IDs 16 | <not exist> | <not exist> | <not exist> | <not exist> |
|  | name IDs 17 | <not exist> | <not exist> | <not exist> | <not exist> |
|  | name IDs 21 | <not exist> | <not exist> | <not exist> | <not exist> |
|  | name IDs 22 | <not exist> | <not exist> | <not exist> | <not exist> |
| OS/2 | version | 0x0001 | 0x0001 | 0x0001 | 0x0001 |
|  | usWeightClass | 400 | 400 | 700 | 700 |
|  | fsSelection | 0x0080 | 0x0280 | 0x0080 | 0x0280 |

Comment: It would be helpful to know what data was populated into the 'head' table (macStyle field), 'name' table (name IDs 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 16, 17, 21 and 22) and 'OS/2' table (usWeightClass and fsSelection) in the fonts. You could provide a pointer to the fonts, or use a tool like OTLMaster Light 3.7 to inspect those values.

Comment: @PeterConstable, updated with table filed values.

Comment: The values you added aren't unreasonable. In the OS/2.fsSelection field, bit 9 (0x0200) indicates "oblique", while bit 0 (0x0001) indicates "italic". Some software considers oblique as the same thing as italic, though they are distinct. So, _maybe_ the fact that bit 9 is set but bit 1 is not set was creating some confusion, though I wouldn't have expected that. One other thing you could add to the table is the value of the macStyle field in the 'head' table.

Comment: What tool can be used to change these values on an existed font file?